# Waiting until an asynchronous call is complete before running the "override" functions of a View Controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I am creating an app that fetches stock data from Alpha Vantage and displays it, as a first attempt at Swift (I usually develop in JS).

More precisely, I have a table view, and each cell has the following labels:

- "Open" price label
- "High" price label
- "Low" price label
- "Close" price label
- "Volume" label

This is the custom class I'm using for the cell.

```
    import UIKit

    class StockChoiceCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var openPriceLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var highPriceLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var lowPriceLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var closePriceLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var volumeLabel: UILabel!

    }
```

I have an asynchronous function that successfully retrieves the desired data from Alpha Vantage and returns `[DataPoint]`, where DataPoint is a struct that contains the open, high, low and close prices, as well as the volume. I say successful, as I use the function in another facet of the app without issues.

That function resembles:

```
func retrieveDataFromAPI (tic: String, completion: @escaping ([DataPoint])->()) {

// Fetch stuff

// Pack it under the DataPoint structure

// ...

completion(arrayOfDataPoints)

}
```

## Here is the issue.

Due to the asynchronous nature of the function, I do not know how to make the application "wait" for the data fetching to complete before running:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! StockChoiceCell

        // ... Setting stuff, etc.

        return cell
    }
```

I searched online, trying primarily the following two posts, as one of my attempts consisted of nesting the asynchronous function within another synchronous function:

- [How to return a bool to the outside function when you have nested functions in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106060/how-to-return-a-bool-to-the-outside-function-when-you-have-nested-functions-in-s)
- [Wait until an asynchronous api call is completed - Swift/IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788434/wait-until-an-asynchronous-api-call-is-completed-swift-ios)

If this were JS, I'd immediately use a Promise. But Swift is new to me, and I am still exploring how asynchronous functions work in the language.

Thank you!

Comment: Does `.reloadData()` on the `UITableView` work for what you are looking for? Just call it when you have all the data from your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Due to the asynchronous nature of the function, I do not know how to make the application "wait" for the data fetching to complete before running `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Well, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will automatically "not execute", when there are no data supplied to the table view. Remember that this is a table view data source method. You don't get to call it directly. So just implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as you would normally. If `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0, then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would not be called, would it?

I would imagine you have implemented `numberOfRowsInSection` with a line like this:

```
return dataSource.count
```

where `dataSource` is a property of your VC, of type `[DataPoint]`. Initially, set this `dataSource` property to an empty array:

```
var dataSource = [DataPoint]()
```

And when the table view loads, it will display nothing, because the data has not been fetched. Now in `viewDidLoad`, we call this async function to fetch the data:

```
retrieveDataFromAPI(tic: "some string") {
    dataFetched in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dataSource = dataFetched
        self.tableView.reloadData() // this calls the table view data source methods again
    }
}
```

At the time you call `reloadData`, `dataSource` will no longer be empty, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called for the appropriate index paths.

---

Note that there is [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) for Swift, which you may or may not find familiar.

Comment: That did the trick! Your code worked perfectly and your main point that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called when the array is empty (a point also made by @Sh_Khan) was very interesting and useful to me as well. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the table before the request and show activity indicator , then show it inside the completion success block , btw `cellForRowAt` won't be called when`numberOfRowsInSection` returns zero ( intial count of the table data source array ) when the table loads before response returns

```
retrieveDataFromAPI(tic:<##>) { res in
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.arr = res
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. You and @George_E mention using `.reloadData()`, which indeed seems very promising. However, how would I set the `result` data to the labels? Do I need to use this snippet within the `tableView cellForRowAt` function?